# How to find duplicate digits in the middle of similar numbers?

Tags: sql-server

In my table, a column has the following values:

```
1234567890
2086567845
    ^^^^ duplicate digits
```

So the above values have 4 digits in the middle which are duplicates.

- How could I find these automatically?

Comment: Is the middle 4 in this case 678?

Comment: How do you define "middle values"? are they always 4 digits? do they always begin in the 5th position?

Comment: I think you're making this problem needlessly complex by (1) only showing one example, (2) using consecutive numbers, (3) not defining the output. Do you want true/false if there are duplicates, the duplicate numbers themselves -- what if they're noncontigious? What does "middle values" mean here?

Comment: How can `7` be duplicate if it only exists in one place? The more I look at this the more I think you mean to say `consecutive` and not duplicate.

Comment: Will the values always have the same length, and is the length known beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method for doing that.  It assumes that the strings are all the same length and you really want to find all the cases where the middle string is duplicated.

Finds all duplicate "middle", update the CTE_Split to use your actual table and column names as appropriate.

```
;WITH CTE_Split AS
    (
    SELECT ID
        , LEFT(ValueString, 4) AS PreFix
        , SUBSTRING(ValueString, 5, 4) AS Middle
        , RIGHT(ValueString, 2) AS Ending
    FROM (VALUES (1, '1234567890')
                , (2, '2086567845')
                ) AS P (ID, ValueString)
    )
, CTE_Duplicate AS
    (
    SELECT ID
        , Prefix
        , Middle
        , Ending
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Middle ORDER BY ID)
    FROM CTE_Split
    )
SELECT ID, Prefix, Middle, Ending, RN 
FROM CTE_Duplicate 
WHERE Middle IN (   SELECT Middle 
                    FROM CTE_Duplicate 
                    WHERE RN >= 2
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of character-based columns, you can check for duplicates using T-SQL using a combination of `CROSS APPLY`, `SUBSTRING`, and `PIVOT`.

```
DECLARE @b TABLE (val varchar(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @b (val)
VALUES ('0123456789')
    , ('3210456987')
    , ('AAAAAAAAAA');

;WITH v AS (
    SELECT v.num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(num)
), x AS (
SELECT b.val
    , t.c
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.val ORDER BY b.val)
FROM @b b
CROSS APPLY v
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(b.val, v.num + 1, 1)))t(c)
)
, y AS (
SELECT *
FROM x
PIVOT (MAX(x.c)
    FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
    )
p
)
SELECT y1.val
    , y2.val
    , Char1 = CASE WHEN y1.[1] = y2.[1] THEN y1.[1] ELSE NULL END
    , Char2 = CASE WHEN y1.[2] = y2.[2] THEN y1.[2] ELSE NULL END
    , Char3 = CASE WHEN y1.[3] = y2.[3] THEN y1.[3] ELSE NULL END
    , Char4 = CASE WHEN y1.[4] = y2.[4] THEN y1.[4] ELSE NULL END
    , Char5 = CASE WHEN y1.[5] = y2.[5] THEN y1.[5] ELSE NULL END
    , Char6 = CASE WHEN y1.[6] = y2.[6] THEN y1.[6] ELSE NULL END
    , Char7 = CASE WHEN y1.[7] = y2.[7] THEN y1.[7] ELSE NULL END
    , Char8 = CASE WHEN y1.[8] = y2.[8] THEN y1.[8] ELSE NULL END
    , Char9 = CASE WHEN y1.[9] = y2.[9] THEN y1.[9] ELSE NULL END
    , Char10 = CASE WHEN y1.[10] = y2.[10] THEN y1.[10] ELSE NULL END
FROM y y1
INNER JOIN y y2 ON y1.val <> y2.val AND
    ( y1.[1] = y2.[1]
    OR y1.[2] = y2.[2]
    OR y1.[3] = y2.[3]
    OR y1.[4] = y2.[4]
    OR y1.[5] = y2.[5]
    OR y1.[6] = y2.[6]
    OR y1.[7] = y2.[7]
    OR y1.[8] = y2.[8]
    OR y1.[9] = y2.[9]
    OR y1.[10] = y2.[10]
    )
```

The results:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║    val     ║    val     ║ Char1 ║ Char2 ║ Char3 ║ Char4 ║ Char5 ║ Char6 ║ Char7 ║ Char8 ║ Char9 ║ Char10 ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 3210456987 ║ 0123456789 ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║     4 ║     5 ║     6 ║ NULL  ║     8 ║ NULL   ║
║ 0123456789 ║ 3210456987 ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║     4 ║     5 ║     6 ║ NULL  ║     8 ║ NULL   ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

The code will return rows where any single character matches another row in the same character position.  This could be modified to only return rows where there are a specific number of matches, however I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Undoubtedly, this will not scale well at all.  However, that is not what this question is about.